# Netlogo Create a Graph

Tags: graph, netlogo, population

I need help starting and understanding how to use Netlog, I know nothing about it.  I want to make a graph where the y coordinate is the population and it starts at 100 but cannot go lower than 0.  the x value is time, and it starts at 0. I want to place buttons that will affect the graph, If i want the population to divide by two as long as the program is running by having the switch "on" on the button.

I have looked everywhere but all they talk about is setting up turtles.  Can I get an example of how to set up a graph on netlogo.

Comment: Take a look at the "Plotting" section of the NetLogo programming guide (https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#plotting).

Comment: Plotting is covered in the tutorial sections of the NetLogo User Manual, too.